# Visual Studio 2010 Debug Server Not Recognizing My Changes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, cassini

Using Visual Studio 2010 on Window 7 64bit. I'm trying to test a website project (not a web application project) using the built in dev server (cassini). The problem I'm having is that when I make a change, I now have to actually stop debugging, kill cassini, and restart before I can actually see my changes in the browser. I used to be able to edit and refresh. One of my fellow developers here is able to do this just fine with an identical setup (same project/vs version/os - and settings near as I can tell). I'm beginning to suspect some sort of permissions issue. I've been all over google trying to find an answer to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this was my fault... I had experienced the dreaded "network BIOS command limit has been reached" issue. I found a post that recommended doing a regedit hack "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET\FCNMode = 1", well this basically turns off File Change Notifications. Changing this value to 2, and applying the changes recommended in knowledge base 810886 fixed both problems.